# How to manually copy folder to /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/?

Tags: python, heroku, importerror, psycopg2

I have deployed my local python web service project to Heroku. I have all my dependencies in requirement.txt file. But, one module psycopg2 is not getting installed properly and I am getting installation error. So, I removed it from requirement.txt and thought I will push everything to heroku first, and then I will manually copy the psycopg2 module folder in `/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages folder`. But I don't know how to access this folder!

Can you please help?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: when I am installing psycopg2 on Heroku, I am getting the error python - error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat when I am trying to pip install psycopg2. I checked many online helps. I did setting of Visual STudio version also. But no luck yet. Can you please help me with this? If I can properly install psycopg2, then everything will work fine!

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the `psycopg2` directory in the same directory of apps, but that's actually a hack and you should try fix on installing `psycopg2` on Heroku.

Comment: when I am installing psycopg2 on Heroku, I am getting the error python - error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat when I am trying to pip install psycopg2. I checked many online helps. I did setting of Visual STudio version also. But no luck yet. Can you please help me with this? If I can properly install psycopg2, then everything will work fine!